# Stripe Webhook is giving me a 308 redirecting error

Tags: stripe-payments, next.js13

[image]

I did refer to [stripe docs](https://support.stripe.com/questions/webhooks-what-to-do-when-the-http-status-code-starts-with-a-three-(3xx)) and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062050/stripe-webhook-returning-308-error-when-calling-vercel-serverless-function):

But i am still stuck around with the same issue in both production and development. As you can see its redirecting me with a 308.

My current webhook endpoint format looks like this:

```
https://mydomain.vercel.app/api/webhooks/stripe/
```

The site is hosted on vercel and i am using nextjs. i havent worked with webhooks or with stripe. its all new to me and have been stuck here for so long.

I am also using the clerk webhook. thats why i am using a parent directory called webhooks, which have two child directories `/clerk/route.ts` and `/stripe/route.ts`.

This is my `/api/webhooks/stripe` api route:

```js
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { db } from "@/db";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body = await req.text();
  const signature = headers().get("Stripe-Signature") as string;
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!);

  let event: Stripe.Event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      body,
      signature,
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!
    );
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    return new NextResponse(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`, { status: 400 });
  }

  const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;

  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
    session.subscription as string
  );
  if (event.type === "charge.succeeded") {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log("Charge succeeded");
    console.log("====================================");
  }
  if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
      session.subscription as string
    );

    await db.user.update({
      where: {
        id: session.client_reference_id as string,
      },
      data: {
        credits: {
          increment: 5,
        },
      },
    });
  }

  if (event.type === "payment_intent.payment_failed") {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log("Payment failed");
    console.log("====================================");
  }

  if (event.type === "payment_intent.succeeded") {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log("Payment succeeded");
    console.log("====================================");
  }

  if (event.type === "payment_intent.created") {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log("Payment created");
    console.log("====================================");
  }

  if (event.type === "customer.created") {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log("Customer created");
    console.log("====================================");
  }

  if (event.type === "invoice.payment_succeeded") {
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
      session.subscription as string
    );
  }

  return new NextResponse(null, { status: 200 });
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The 308 error means your server is trying to do a permanent redirect, [which Stripe webhooks don't support](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#fix-http-status-codes). You need to make sure your webhook endpoint URL has no redirections and return a 200 status.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. How do i do that @soma.